# Java: Detecting User Input as Day of The Year

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

For this programming assignment, my professor wants our programs to detect user input as the day of the year using arrays. There are two separate arrays for months: `String[] Months = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};` and days per month: `int[] DaysofMonth = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};`.

Here is how the program should work: if I enter 62, then the program should do this calculation: 62 - (31 + 28) = 62 - 59 = 3. Then I assigned each calculation to a month. For example, month = Months[2] where day = day - 59. So the output should be "Mar 3". Here is the code so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab5_MonthandDay
  {
  public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
  
    int i;
    int day;
    String month;
  
    String[] Months = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    int[] DaysofMonth = { 31,     28,    31,    30,    31,    30,    31,   31,    30,    31,    30,    31  };
  
    while (true)
     {
     System.out.print("Enter a day of the year: ");
     day = kb.nextInt();
     
     while ((day >= 1) && (day <= 365))
       {
       for (i = 0; i < Months.length; ++i)
        { 
        if (day <= 31) //--Jan
           {
           month = Months[0];
           System.out.println(month + " " + day);
           } 
        if ((day >= 31) && (day <= 59)) //--Feb
           {
           month = Months[1]; 
           day = DaysofMonth[i] - 31;
           System.out.println(month + " " + day); 
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

If I run this program, if I put 5, the program will print Jan 5. But the program will create an infinite loop. I also am not sure how or where to implement the second array in the program. I tried assigning DaysofMonth[i] = day, which still caused an infinite loop. If I put in 35, the program will output an infinite loop looking something like this:
`Enter a day of the year: Feb 0 Jan 28 Jan 31 Feb 0 Jan 30 Jan 31...Enter a day of the year:`. This program is very confusing to me and I have no idea how to solve it. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

this will work as you ask :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] Months = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
        
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter a day of the year: ");
            int day = kb.nextInt();

            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, day);
            
            System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+" "+Months[c.get(Calendar.MONTH)]);

        }

}
```

Comment: When answering a homework question, it's usually best to explain what the asker was doing wrong. See "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)" for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution but it works :) I also used IO. instead of scanner but scanner works fine aswell

```
public class orjekct {

    static String[] Months = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    static int[] DaysofMonth = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = IO.readInt();
        int end = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int month=0;

        while (end == 0) {
            if (number > DaysofMonth[i]) {
                number = number - DaysofMonth[i];
                month++;
                i++;
            } else {
                end++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("month:" + Months[month] + " day " + number);
    }
}
```

Comment: When answering a homework question, it's usually best to explain what the asker was doing wrong. See "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)" for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a loop to read values from user input and provide an exit condition (e.g. if user enters 0 or negative number).

Then you need to compare `day` to the number of days in the current month, and subtract this number as necessary.

That is:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] monthNames = {
            "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    };
    int[] monthDays = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
      
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter a day of the year or 0 to quit: ");
        int day = kb.nextInt();
            
        if (day <= 0) {
            break;
        } else if (day > 365) {
            day = 1 + day % 365; // ensure day is in range [1..365]
        }
        
        String month = "UNKNOWN";

        for (int i = 0; i < monthDays.length; i++) {
            int dom = monthDays[i]; // days in current i-th month

            if (day <= dom) {
                month = monthNames[i];
                break;
            }
            day -= dom;
        }
         
        System.out.println(month + " " + day);
    }
    System.out.println("Bye!");
}
```

Output

```
Enter a day of the year or 0 to quit: 10
Jan 10
Enter a day of the year or 0 to quit: 200
Jul 19
Enter a day of the year or 0 to quit: 0
Bye!
```